# How to create and sort a singly linked list in runtime?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I am trying to create a linked list from reading a text file and output the words read and their count in an ascending order.

Everything is fine except trying to order nodes in runtime.

First I have tried like bubble sort but I cant wrap my head around the logic at the beginning part of the linked list.

Second I have tried to keep comparing x->next's count until I found one that's bigger than the one I wanted to push back. Then I swap them. I used many pointers but it works sometimes but failed at some edge cases.

I should've saved some of the code to let people point out the flaw of my logic but I was little bit frustrated just trying to start over from scratch.

Can someone provide some good logic or explicit pseudo? Thank you very much

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#define MAX 999
typedef struct Node
{
    char *name;
    int count;
    struct Node *next;
}node;
void insert(node **,char *);
void freeNode(node **);
int main()
{
    char str[MAX];
    node *head = NULL;
    while(getword(str,MAX))
    {
        insert(&head,str);
    }
    print(head);
    free(head);
    return 0;
}
void insert(node **head,char *str)
{
     node *mid = *head;
node *left = NULL, *right = NULL;
while(mid)
{
    if(strcmp(mid->name,str) == 0)
    {
        ++(mid->count);
        node *temp = left;

        while(mid->count > right->count)
        {
            //printf("in %s %s %s\n",left->name,mid->name, right->name);
            left->next = mid->next;
            mid->next = right->next;
            right->next = mid;

            left = left->next;
            if(mid->next != NULL) right = mid->next;
            if(left == mid) break;
            //printf("in %s %s %s\n\n",left->name,mid->name, right->name);
           // sleep(3);
        }

        return;
    }
    left = mid;
    mid = mid->next;
    if(mid != NULL) right = mid->next;
}

    node *newnode = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
    newnode->name = (char *) malloc(MAX * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(newnode->name,str);
    newnode->count = 1;
    newnode->next = *head;
    *head = newnode;
}
void freeNodes(node **head)
{
    node *temp;
    while(*head)
    {
        temp = (*head)->next;
        free(*head);
        (*head) = NULL;
        (*head) = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: To swap the "current" node and the "next of current" node, you need to keep track of the "*previous* of current" node as well. To (bubble) sort, loop over the list, if "current" is larger than "next of current" then swap those two nodes. Do this until no swaps are performed.

Comment: @ Some programmer dude im trying to use left mid and right precurret,current and current->next, but my condiction trying to do current->next always fail and crash the program

Comment: Your purpose is not clear. Do you want to Insert into an *ordered* list?

Answer (score 0):

I just worked on a few edge case. I make sure when first node get repeated will be make sure to move down by one

```
node *mid = *head;
node *left = NULL, *right = NULL;
while(mid)
{
    if(strcmp(mid->name,str) == 0)
    {
        ++(mid->count);
        if(mid->next == NULL) return;
        node *temp = left;
        if(left == NULL)
        {
            left = mid->next;
            mid->next = left->next;
            left->next = mid;
            *head = left;
            right = mid->next;

        }
            while(mid->count > right->count)
            {
                left->next = mid->next;
                mid->next = right->next;
                right->next = mid;

                left = left->next;
                if(mid->next != NULL) right = mid->next;
                if(left == mid) break;
                //printf("in %s %s %s\n\n",left->name,mid->name, right->name);
               // sleep(3);
            }

        return;
    }
    left = mid;
    mid = mid->next;
    if(mid != NULL) right = mid->next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Google merge-sort. IMHO it is the best algorithm for sorting singly connected lists.

Start with a list nodes:

```
node3 -> node7 -> node1 -> node20 -> node11 -> node13 -> NULL
```

Each subslist of length 1 is (trivially) sorted:

```
{ node3 } is sorted
{ node7 } is sorted
```

Then merge two consecutive sublists of length 1 into sublists of length 2:

```
node3 -> node7 -> node20 -> node1 -> node11 -> node13 -> node007 -> NULL
```

into

```
{node3 -> node7}->{node1 -> node20}->{node11 -> node13}->{node007} -> NULL
```

`node007` is considered equal to `node7`.

Then merge two consecutive sublists of length 2 into subslists of length 4:

```
{node3 -> node7}->{node1 -> node20}->{node11 -> node13}->{node007} -> NULL

merge(node3, node1, 2):
returns {node1 -> node3 -> node7 ->node20}

merge(node11, node007, 2):
returns {node007 -> node11 -> node13}
```

So you get two sorted sublists of length 4:

```
{node1 -> node3 -> node7 ->node20}->{node007 -> node11 -> node13}->NULL 

merge(node1,node007,4):
returns
{node1 -> node3 -> node7 -> node007 -> node11 -> node13 -> ode20}->NULL
```

So the length always doubles, and you are finished when it is equal or greater than the length of the entire list.

The merge alway compares the first element of each list and pops the smaller one from the list and appends it to the result tail:

```
merge(n1 = {node3 -> node7}->t1 , n2 = {node1 -> node20}-> t2 , 2):
```

does

```
count1 = count2 = 2;
result = NULL;
as node1 < node3  : result = { node1 }-> NULL;
                    n2 = { node20 } -> t2;
                    count2 = 1;
as node3 < node20 : result = {node1 -> node3}-> NULL;
                    n1 = {node7}->t1;
                    count1 = 1;
as node7 < node20 : result = {node1 -> node3-> node7 }-> NULL;
                    n1 = t1;
                    count1 = 0; (merge finished);
as count2 != 0 :    result = {node1 -> node3-> node7 -> node20 } -> NULL.
```

This ia all pseudo code that should give you an idea.